# How to convert SOAP API to REST API using python?

Tags: api, python-2.7, soapui

I have to create a python script that should hit a SOAP API and should convert that to Restful API.
I have XSD and WSDL files with me. Can someone help me how to do this in Python ? I have tried different resources but couldn't get the help I need.

Answer (score 0):

we use python Zeep package for accessing WSDL in our automation

https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/